# async and asyncio error -- TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-asyncio

I am trying to get a function to run asynchronously in my Flask application in Python3.x. I am using the `asyncio` library and have put `async` outside of my function declaration, but I am getting an error that reads:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1630, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1740, in make_response
    rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 885, in force_type
    response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 884, in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable
```

My code is as follows:

```
import asyncio

... more function definitions ...

@app.route("/save_to_dbx")
@login_required
async def save_to_dbx():
    """ Saves a course to Dropbox as a .zip """
    # Creating a .zip file out of the course
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile("IoT.zip", "w")
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(BASE_PATH, "static/Content/IoT")):
        for file in files:
            complete__file_path = os.path.join(subdir, file)
            print("Writing to Zip:", complete__file_path)
            zip.write(complete__file_path, complete__file_path.split("/")[-1])
    zip.close()

    # Uploading the .zip to Dropbox
    f = open(os.path.join(BASE_PATH, "IoT.zip"))
    file_size = os.path.getsize(os.path.join(BASE_PATH, "IoT.zip"))

    CHUNK_SIZE = 4 * 1024 * 1024

    print("Upload file size:", file_size)

    if file_size <= CHUNK_SIZE:
        print(__dbx_conn__().files_upload(f, "/VOSW-Backup-Testing/IoT.zip"))
    else:
        upload_session_start_result = __dbx_conn__().files_upload_session_start(f.read(CHUNK_SIZE))
        cursor = dropbox.files.UploadSessionCursor(
            session_id=upload_session_start_result.session_id,
            offset=f.tell())
        commit = dropbox.files.CommitInfo(path="/VOSW-Backup-Testing/IoT.zip")

        while f.tell() < file_size:
            if ((file_size - f.tell()) <= CHUNK_SIZE):
                print(__dbx_conn__().files_upload_session_finish(f.read(CHUNK_SIZE), cursor, commit))
            else:
                __dbx_conn__().files_upload_session_append_v2(f.read(CHUNK_SIZE), cursor)
                cursor.offset = f.tell()

    return """<!DOCTYPE html>
              <html lang="en">
              <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title>Success!</title>
              </head>
              <body>
                <h1>Success!</h1>
              </body>"""
```

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`flask` is not asynchronous. It is not directly compatible with `asyncio` at all, and passing a `async` function to `@app.route` in a flask application won't work.

I suggest using [quart](https://gitlab.com/pgjones/quart) instead.

Comment: Oh quart looks very neat. What about just using general threading? Basically I want to upload to Dropbox but it is super slow, so I want the process to run in the background.

Comment: @agaidis flask already uses threads by default - every request run in its own thread, so you don't have to do anything, while you upload, your application will still be able to answer other requests. I would prefer to go asynchronous though

Comment: thank you for your response. It may be able to take additional requests, but the webpage "freezes" for a user while they wait to upload a 1GB .zip to Dropbox. The group I am working in is pretty tied to Flask, so idk if quart will really fly. Is there anyway at all in Flask that you can think of to achieve this background processing?

Comment: @agaidis I still suggest you should use asynchronous networking - it is the perfect use case for that; Other common way to solve it is a message queue to offload to a worker process. But your process just wants to wait for network so asynchronous is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [Sanic](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It is really fast and handles async requests very well.

with sanic you can consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53663219/runtimeerror-this-event-loop-is-already-running/53665331#53665331) solution.